# Proof of a Thm. required for Descartes' Rule Of signs : if $r\gt0, f(r)= 0$ , $f(x)= (x-r)Q(x)$ and $Q(x)$ has less variation in sign than $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Source : Moses Richardson, *College Algebra* (1947) , §111, page $241$.

Note : Richardson is also the author of a ( to my eyes) admirable introductory book called *Fundamentals Of Mathematics*  ( available at Archive.org).

The theorem reads as follows:

> If $r$  is a positive root of the [polynomial] equation $f(x)=0$ with real
> coefficients , then the quotient $Q(x)$ obtained by dividing $f(x)$ by
> $(x-r)$ has at least one less variation in sign than $f(x)$ has.

The author places himself in the case where the leading coefficient is positive ( which can be obtained without changing the solution set of the equation by multiplying $f(x)$ by $-1$).

He only gives an " outline of the proof" , using as a paradigmatic example  the equation $ f(x)= x^{8}+x^{6}+2x^{5}-4x^{4}-80x^{2}+x+2$

He operates the synthetic division of $f(x)$ by $2$ and reasons on the coefficients of the quotient $Q(x)$ , that is, on the third line of the division tableau.

(1) He first  explains that the first coefficient of $Q(x)$ will be positive and will not change to negative before $f(x)$ changes in sign. So, $Q(x)$ will not have , so far, more change of signs than $f(x)$.

(2) Once the coefficients of $Q(x)$ have ( possibly) become negative, they  will remain so until $f(x)$ changes from negetive to positive . Same consequence as in (1) .

Points (1) and (2) show clearly that $Q(x)$ cannot have more changes of signs than $f(x)$.

The third point aims at establishing the " not more,and even at least one less" part of the theorem.

Here is the argument :

> " Since the last number in the third line of  synthetic division must
> be $0$ the last coefficient of $Q(x)$ must have the opposite sign from
> the last coefficient of $f(x)$ [ this I understand well] . ***Hence*** the
> largest number of variations $Q(x)$  can have is one less than the
> number of variations of $f(x)$ and it may have fewer than that."

I cannot see how what precedes " hence" entails what comes after it.

I suppose the logical link is quite obvious, since Richardson is a lucid and reader friendly author, but I miss something here.

Comment: What is $f(x)?$ A polynomial?

Comment: Yes, the author omits this in the wording of the proof , but the entire section ( " Theory of equations") only deals with polynomial functions.

Comment: A simpler proof is that the since r is a root, dividing f(x) by (x-r) must reduce the number of roots of f(x) by 1. I can't see a need for a more complex procedure.

Comment: @NoChance Here "variations in sign of $f(x)$" is referring to the number of changes in the signs of the coefficients of $f(x)$, not the number of times the graph of $f(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis.

Comment: @BenjaminWright, yes I understand. The Rule of Signs relates number of real roots to sign changes in polynomial coefficients. Ref: https://owlcation.com/stem/Descartes-Rule-of-Signs

Comment: @NoChance But the theorem in question is what's being used to prove Descartes' Rule of Signs, so the connection between sign variations and number of roots hasn't been established yet

Comment: @BenjaminWright, OK, I will look carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading coefficients of $Q(x)$ and $f(x)$ have the same sign, and the last coefficients of $Q(x)$ and $f(x)$ have opposite signs; hence, $Q(x)$ and $f(x)$ have a different number of sign changes. Since $Q(x)$ does not have more sign changes than $f(x)$, it must have fewer.

Comment: Nice , thanks for this concise and convincing answer !